Can these two Python functions be replaced by a single generic one taking either a list or a tuple argument?
Can these two Python functions:
def negativeList(a):
  return [-e for e in a]

def negativeTuple(a):
  return tuple(-e for e in a)

be replaced by an equvalent single generic function negative(a)?

You changed the function signature

@Tarik What do you mean?

Are you assuming that negativeList actually takes a list (and not an arbitrary iterable value) as an argument?

@chepner That was my assumption expressed in the function name.

You can determine the type at run time
def negative(a):
    return type(a)(-e for e in a)


You can use the isinstance function to check the type of the input and then return the appropriate type.
def negative_sequence(a):
    if isinstance(a, list):
        return [-e for e in a]
    elif isinstance(a, tuple):
        return tuple(-e for e in a)
    else:
        raise TypeError("Input must be a list or a tuple")

# Example usage:
print(negative_sequence([1, 2, 3]))  # Output: [-1, -2, -3]
print(negative_sequence((1, 2, 3)))  # Output: (-1, -2, -3)


I believe that's what single dispatch decorators can be used for:
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def negative(arg):
    return f'unsupported type: {type(arg)}'

@negative.register
def _(arg: tuple):
    return tuple(-e for e in arg)

@negative.register
def _(arg: list):
    return list(-e for e in arg)

print(negative(10))
print(negative('abc'))
print(negative([1, 2, 4]))
print(negative((1, 2, 3)))

Notes:

I would rather raise an exception than return an error string, that part is just for easier demonstration.
You can further differentiate by using e.g. list[int] or tuple[float], the linked documentation has examples there and a websearch should turn up many more.


So we can also use the Iterable class making it more robust
from collections.abc import Iterable
import numpy as np


def negative(a):
    if isinstance(a, Iterable):
        result = (-e for e in a)
        if isinstance(a, list):
            return list(result)
        elif isinstance(a, tuple):
            return tuple(result)
        elif isinstance(a, np.ndarray):
            return np.negative(a)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Not supported iterable type.")
    else:
        raise TypeError("Interables only.")


Downvote, way too much code: negative = lambda a: type(a)(map(lambda e: -e, a)) is enough. ;)

ok will change :) it

The Python style guide recommends to not use lambdas for situations like this; you’re just declaring a regular function. Lambdas should be used only for inline functions as arguments.

@deceze oh ok ok aye aye captain I will find a better solution promise :)
